# psycopg2 declare connection name and info

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

how can i declare connection information in psycopg?
is that possible?

in pg_hero we can manage and view all connections!
I realized that some tools like metabase send connection information
[image]
so I wonder is that possible in psycopg or not?
what is that ability name anyway?
I saw the info class in connection (psycopg2.extensions.ConnectionInfo(connection))
But I couldn't find any example for using it

Comment: Where do you see a "connection name" in there?  All of that is just implementation details for metabase.  You don't need it on psycopg2.